# What type of electric motor drive can be used for keeping a load at specific heights?

Tags: motor, control

We are planning to adjust the level of a load (around 50 kg) by using an electrical motor. Now we are using a hand crank and we want to get rid of this manual process.

For example we want to implement a control where one can adjust the height of the load. The load is hanging down on a pulley. We want to keep the load at 4 different fixed heights by using an easy push button system or a computer. When one sends signal to the motor the motor will adjust the load to a particular height depending on the signal and then will stop there.

What type of motor and electronic control can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done with an electric brake attached to the motor.  The brake mechanically keeps the motor from turning when not energized.  When you press the button and the motor starts to turn the brake is released so the motor can turn.

If you want finer control over the speed of the motor you can use a Variable Frequency Drive (VFD). This would still use the same motor brake arraingment. VFDs in lifting and hoisting applications almost always have a braking resistor to counteract the ability for the inertia of the load to overdrive the motor.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is known as "floating the load" in the industry. Flux-vector variable frequency drives can do this, but they're expensive and big; being able to produce 100% torque at zero speed is no small feat, and I doubt you'll be happy with the price tag for a control for such a small motor.

I think you'd be better off with a cone clutch; when the clutch is disengaged it's a brake, and when it's engaged your motor can move the load. Other braking systems would also work.